# Problem with internet over WiFi

Tags: internet, wireless-router

I have a problem that I just can't find the solution for.

I have a D-Link DIR-635 WireLess router that is connected to my ASDL internet connection.

This setup works just fine, but several times a week internet stops working over WiFi. When this happens, there are some things I have noticed that are also always true:

1. The signal strength on the WiFi connection is still maxed out, so I'm not disconnected from the router.
2. If I try to access the router using the web based interface from my browser, that is not accessible. I can't ping it either. This is feel is strange since I'm still connected to the wireless network.
3. If any copying is going on between machines on the LAN this also stops working at the same time.
4. When this happens, it happen to all machines at once, so it can't be anything related to the setup on one of the machines.

So it seems that even if all my machines still connected to the router, both internet and local network goes down, and the only way I know how to solve it now, is to plug the power cord out of the router, and put it back in. This *usually* solves the problem, but sometimes I have to repeat it to get it solved.

This is, as you probably understand, extremely annoying, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

One more thing is that it seems that the activity lights on the router itself indicate a lot of traffic even when all connected machines are shut down.

**EDIT**
According to Iszi's comment I'll give some more information.

The setup is in a appartment building. I have not notices anything special regarding the indicator lights, but I'll see if there is something special about them the next time this happens.

My security settings are set to *WPA-Personal*.

Comment: Are you in a house, or apartment building?  Which specific indicator lights are flashing when the machines are shut down?  Does your wireless network require encryption and authentication?  If so, what kinds?

Comment: I have added some more information now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it was an issue with a computer, only one of the computers would stop working (like you said). If it was an issue with the ISP, you should still be able to log into the router with the web interface and you should still be able to communicate between the local computers. It sounds to me like there is an issue with the router. You can try messing around with the router settings if you like. Maybe try a new router firmware or set it up with a stronger password. Maybe put a fan on it to prevent it from overheating. Ultimately I think the fix would be to get a new wireless router.